# Flutter: update Firebase snapshot data

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I have these 3 pages:

- A: with a list of items. This list is a stream coming from Firebase
- B: Item info
- C: Item update

In B I show whatever I send from A. Same for C. When I modify the element this does the update in Firebase. Until here it's ok.

When it updates the item we move back again to B and here I need to update the snapshot data, because in this page we have something like this:

```
Text(widget.data['item']['title']);
```

I need to do `widget.data['item']['title'] = 'New title';`? Or it possible to modify the whole item like `widget.data['item'].data() = newItem;` (this doesn't work)?

In page B:

```
await Navigator.of(context)
        .pushNamed(
      "/new-item", // page C
      arguments: widget.data["item"], // this is the snapshot
    )
        .then((dynamic updatedItem) async { // this is the map
      if (lease != null) {
        setState(() {
          // widget.data["item"] = updatedItem; // this is the main problem. First contains a snapshot and second is the map
        });
        await firebaseProfile.updateLease(context, item);
      }
 });
```

///

```
await db
        .collection('items')
        .doc(item.id) // since I get the map this doesn't work
        .update(item);
```

Comment: Have you considered putting a `ChangeNotifierProvider` above widget `B` and updating it from widget `C` so that `B` will be rebuilt? (

Comment: I only used ChangeNotifierProvider in providers. You mean I could use this for a normal StatefulWidget then? I can also move the item to my provider when moving to B and in C update the provider but was thinking if there is a better way for that

Comment: In this situation, after updating in page C, I pop page C and Page B and then push in a new Page B (and it usually has the updated data). To do that, I do something like this `Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, PageB, ModalRoute.withName('PageA'));`.

Comment: I mean with provider.

Comment: @PeterObiechina that's what I do but that contains a map, not a snapshot. I need to update item.data(), not just item. Add an example if I didn't understand you well.

Comment: @PeterKoltai I know how to do it with provider, but I want to know if is possible to update the snapshot data directly

Comment: If I understand correctly, you update the Firebase collection, so the changes will be streamed to widget A, but you need a rebuild in widget B as well based on the updated data, is it right?

Comment: @PeterKoltai tbh the problem comes even before updating. I added more code to make it more clear. Before calling the update function I already have the map, not the updated snapshot and there is where I need to update the snapshot.data()

Comment: Even if you could update somehow the snapshot, IMO it is not a good solution (anyway, I think `setState` would not work with `widget.data`, only with a state class member). But what if your `updateLease` method fails for any reason (connection etc.)? Do you want to update your UI with data that is not in sync with the database? I suggest using a `StreamProvider` in widget A, consume it in widget B, make the update in widget C and let your UI update according to the streamed changes.

Comment: Or: pass only the map to widget B from widget A, or an object created from the snapshot data. In this case you can simple update it after routing back from C, by using a stateful widget and storing the data in a the state class member variable.

Comment: if updateLease fails for any reason it doesn't update the item with the new data, that's why I have the check for.
I was passing before just the map but found it easier to pass the snapshot since I had access to its ID directly without passing it as well

Comment: also as mentioned, page B has its own state. So if I go back to page A, I have the list of items updated, but not in B when I update. I have to go back to A and move to B again to have it. But when I update the item in B I need to update the state as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In resume, this is not possible, I couldn't find any way to update the snapshot so I had to change the logic.

This is a different approach I have used:

```
 void initState() {
    itemCopy = widget.data['item'].data();
    super.initState();
  }
```

and keep the setState, in this case updating `itemCopy` instead. So whenever I need to get the id I'll use `widget.data['item'].id()` and `itemCopy` for the info